# How to check for mutability in syn's `PatType`?

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I have gotten a `PatType` from an `FnArg::Typed(my_pat_type)` which I got by extracting the inputs from a function signature in a procedural macro.

My problem is that I need a concise way to check if my `PatType` is in any way mutable or not, without going into the specific information.

I tried checking the documentation for a method, or something to tell me if a `PatType` is mutable, but I instead found the `pat` and `ty` fields, which are themselves `enum`'s that I don't really want to match against to get the specific information, and check mutability there.

I tried asking ChatGPT but it gave me a huge mess of spaghetti code that *does* match against those `enum`'s

Comment: You cannot do that in general, because mutable references can be hidden inside types, and interior mutability also cannot be observed by macros.

Comment: It's completely unclear to me what you want to check for. Would you consider any of these mutable? `mut x: i32`, `x: &mut i32`, `(x, mut y): (i32, i32)`

Comment: Yes, I would consider those mutable.

Comment: I want to check mutability to decide between generating either an `Fn` or `FnMut`. In other words if the argument wouldn't work in an `Fn` and would need an `FnMut`, I would consider it mutable. I don't care about interior mutability.

Comment: You still need to know when there is a mutable reference hidden in the type, so you cannot do that.

Comment: Although how would a mutable reference be hidden in the type? Do you mean hard to find or not in the signature at all?

Comment: E.g. `struct Ty<'a> { v: &'a mut String }` Then you have a parameter of type `Ty` and you cannot know that it hides a mutable reference.